# Entity framework entity class mapping with a plain .NET class

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have the following in [Entity Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET_Entity_Framework).

Table - Country

Fields

- List item
- Country_ID
- Dialing_Code
- ISO_Alpha2
- ISO_Alpha3
- ISO_Full

I would like to map only selected fields from this entity model to my domain class.

My domain model class is

```
public class DomainCountry
{
    public int Country_ID { get; set; }
    public string Dialing_Code { get; set; }
    public string ISO_3166_1_Alpha_2 { get; set; }
}
```

The following will work, however insert or update is not possible. In order to get insert or update we need to use **ObjectSet<>**, but it will not support in my case.

```
IQueryable<DomainCountry> countries =
    context.Countries.Select(
        c =>
        new DomainCountry
            {
                Country_ID = c.Country_Id,
                Dialing_Code = c.Dialing_Code,
                ISO_3166_1_Alpha_2 = c.ISO_3166_1_Alpha_2
            });
```

Is there a nice solution for this? It wound be really fantastic.

Ideally it will be kind of *proxy class* which will support all the futures however highly customizable.

**That is, only the columns we want to expose to the outer world**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term for "plain .NET classes" is [POCO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_CLR_Object) - plain old CLR objects (inspired by [POJO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object), plain old Java objects).

Read this blog post series, it helped me a lot:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/05/21/poco-in-the-entity-framework-part-1-the-experience.aspx

Comment: I saw the above blog and they have explained some thing which is almost similat to LINQ to SQL. The only difference is instead of Datacontext they have used object context and on behalf of GetTable<> they have used CreateObjectSet. I do not find more difference. If any other way could you extend your help on this.

Comment: @Elan what they do is just what EF generator does for standard cases. you just might not seen EF generator output. why don't you like that approach?

Comment: I want the entire entity model, in addition to that I have a domain model and it is expossed to the WCF Servie. Due to the outer world exposure I do not want allow secured or important key fields to to be expossed. It is almost SQL View case.

Answer (score 0):

I want to do the same thing. My goal is to build a WCF service that can use the same set of objects as the application I'm building by sharing a DLL and sending/receiving the same classes. Additionally, I also wanted to limit what fields are exposed. After thinking about this for a while it seems a user-defined cast might do the trick. Have a look to see if it works for you.

http://www.roque-patrick.com/windows/final/bbl0065.html